# Texture not moving when rigged object moves, and assigning to generated causes more problems

Tags: node-editor, procedural, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping

Basically, I have a procedural texture assigned to an object that I have that when one of the bones moves, the texture appears to slide across the mesh.

I have seen how to fix this, being to assign the nodes to the generated or UV texture coordinate, but this causes my mesh to turn into an amalgamated mesh of sorts. So, I was wondering how to make my texture move with my mesh without turning my mesh into something that it was not originally.

For reference:
Original
[image]

Now using Generated
[image]

Comment: Both Object and Generated outputs will give a semi-persistent texture in 3D space, meaning if your mesh polygons move in 3D space, the texture at location A will not follow along to location B, you'll sample the 3D texture at another location, giving you a different result. You need to use UV coordinates, but for that you need to correctly UV-unwrap your mesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Object* output won't work, the texture will move as soon as you'll animate your object, *Generated* should work though but first make sure that you've applied the scale of your object, and also you need to correct the stretching with the *Scale* values of a *Mapping* node, because *Generated* will take the proportions of your object into account and if it's tall for example the texture will stretch on Z:

[image]